# How to append ellipse inside datagrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF, I have a datagrid with 6 columns and I fill my datagrid with data, what I am trying to do is to put a small circle beside the first value in my first column "Tag_Name" and each circle has a different color in each row. now I am stuck I created a stackpanel then I created myEllipse but I do not know how to append the Ellipse beside the Tag_Name

[image: just like that]

```
  public class Table
        {

            public string Tag_Name { get; set; }
            public string Tag_Comment { get; set; }
            public float Value { get; set; }
            public string Unit { get; set; }
            public float Lower { get; set; }
            public float Upper { get; set; }

        }
        public List<Table> datagrid_List = new List<Table>();


StackPanel myStackPanel = new StackPanel();

// Create a red Ellipse.
Ellipse myEllipse = new Ellipse();

// Create a SolidColorBrush with a red color to fill the
// Ellipse with.
SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();

// Describes the brush's color using RGB values.
// Each value has a range of 0-255.
mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 0);
myEllipse.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;
myEllipse.StrokeThickness = 2;
myEllipse.Stroke = Brushes.Black;

// Set the width and height of the Ellipse.
myEllipse.Width = 8;
myEllipse.Height = 2;
myStackPanel.Children.Add(myEllipse);
```

Here I append the data to my gridview but I do not know how to add the stackpanel besidt the tag name

```
datagrid_List.Add(new Table { Tag_Name = myStackPanel + "Tag1" , Tag_Comment = "", Value = 8, Unit = "kj/h", Lower = 9, Upper = 28 });
datagrid_List.Add(new Table { Tag_Name = myStackPanel  + "Tag2", Tag_Comment = "", Value = 45, Unit = "kj/h", Lower = 9, Upper = 12 });
datagrid_List.Add(new Table { Tag_Name = myStackPanel  + "Tag3", Tag_Comment = "", Value = 25, Unit = "kj/h", Lower = 9, Upper = 98 });
dataGrid.ItemsSource = datagrid_List;
```

Comment: Adding UI elements should be done in the Cell Template or in its Content Template.
Since you haven't shown the XAML that creates the «datagrid_List» and its columns, it's impossible to show how this can be done. Also, to get an answer, you must explain which property of the «Table» class and how the color of the circle should depend on.

Comment: How do you define the columns of `datagrid_List`? Or are they auto-generated?

Comment: I edited the code to include that datagrid_List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with a `CellTemplate` in your XAML markup and put the `StackPanel` in there:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid_List" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Tag Name">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Ellipse Width="8" Height="2" Fill="Red" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tag_Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tag Comment" Binding="{Binding Tag_Comment}" />
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thank you brother you are correct, but what if I have an  array of colors in the backend code and I want each new ellipse to have new color from that array?